# Unable to run Continuous Flight Recorder for Java app running as a service on Windows10

Tags: java, windows, profiling, jmc, jfr

I'm trying to profile a Java application, which is running as a Service in Windows 10(64 bit) using Java flight recorder `dumponexit` option. During the execution, Windows does create a temporary directory and temporary .jfr file. However, the final JFR file isn't created in the default directory or the user-defined directory.
The exact options used are `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true`.

This set of options does work perfectly on any java application which is run using `java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true -jar <AppName>`.

In another case, if I use `-XX:StartFlightRecording` option with a defined time duration, then Java Flight Recorder creates the file in the given directory as expected. The exact options used are `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=delay=20s,duration=60s,name=MyRecording,filename=C:\myrecording.jfr`

My requirement says I need to use the former option for profiling. That is, whenever the said Windows services start, the profiling is enabled and whenever the service stops, the profiling stops and .jfr file is generated.

If anyone has used continuous recording and solved this issue then the solution would be much appreciated.

**Update:** After setting log level to trace following logs are generated.
Options used: `-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=C:\,loglevel=trace`

```
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 1252] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 1252] Running 'XYZ' Service...
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 6292] Starting service...
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][INFO ][0.000] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] JFR log level set. Log level now at [TRACE]
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.163] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Loaded JFR library
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][INFO ][0.191] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Using C:\Windows\Temp\2018_02_20_10_36_23_12304 as Flight Recorder repository.
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.216] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Default settings loaded.
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.218] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Shutdown hook registered
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.224] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] VMJFR created.
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.272] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] RedefineClass successful
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.274] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] RedefineClass successful
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.277] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] RedefineClass successful
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.288] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Java started. Took 127 ms
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.290] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Starting up default recording
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [13316] [jfr][DEBUG][0.292] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [13316] Bufferthread started.
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][INFO ][0.427] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Starting recording [id=0, name=HotSpot default, start=Tue Feb 20 10:36:23 GMT 2018]
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.429] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Binding recording [id=0, name=HotSpot default, start=Tue Feb 20 10:36:23 GMT 2018]
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.431] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Default recording started
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] [jfr][TRACE][0.433] 
[2018-02-20 10:36:23] [info]  [ 7944] Finished starting default recording
[2018-02-20 10:36:25] [info]  [ 6292] Service started in 1799 ms.
[2018-02-20 10:37:40] [info]  [ 9208] Stopping service...
[2018-02-20 10:37:42] [info]  [ 9208] Service stop thread completed.
[2018-02-20 10:38:42] [info]  [ 1252] Run service finished.
[2018-02-20 10:38:42] [info]  [ 1252] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that it is (file) permission related. The user running the Windows service is probably not the same as when you start the Java process from the shell. That said, you were able to get a recording when you set a duration, so that theory doesn't hold.

When you specify dumponexit=true, the dump is carried out in a Java shutdown hook. If the process is not terminated properly, i.e. the process is killed forcefully, the hooks will never get a chance to run.

If you can get a log, I would try to start it with -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=loglevel=trace and see if you see any error messages.

Comment: I have updated description along trace level logs. I can't see any trace or debug logs while stopping the service. I noticed another behavior, where the temporary file is not generated in the temp directory. It is random behavior. Sometimes the Temp directory contains .jfr file(0KB) and along with it, .jfr.part file(463KB) at the end of the service. So in a way, data is being captured but not dumped into a file.

Comment: I think it is a permission issue where you can't write to C:\.  Try to set the filename to the temp directory (where the process has access). If that doesn't work, it's probably because the process is killed prematurely. 

The JVM should not leave .part and .jfr files in the temp directory if the process gets a chance to run the shutdown hooks.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why it isn't creating the file. Finally, I made it work by converting the Service into an App.